# sqlite combining select results for searching

Tags: sqlite

Alright so here are my two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [cards] (
  [id] TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
  [game_id] TEXT NOT NULL,
  [set_id] TEXT CONSTRAINT [id_set_id] REFERENCES [sets]([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE MATCH SIMPLE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE, 
  [name] TEXT NOT NULL, 
  [image] TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE [custom_properties] (
  [id] TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
  [card_id] TEXT CONSTRAINT [id_card_id] REFERENCES [cards]([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE MATCH SIMPLE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,
  [game_id] TEXT CONSTRAINT [id_game_id4] REFERENCES [games]([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE MATCH SIMPLE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE, 
  [name] TEXT NOT NULL, 
  [type] INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  [vint] INTEGER, 
  [vstr] TEXT);
```

What I would like to do is to have a search that grabs all the data from the `cards` row, and then adds the column who's name is `(where custom_properties.card_id == cards.id).name`.
Then I would like it's value to be `vint` if `type == 1`, else `vstr`.

So, here is an example dataset

cards

```
|id | game_id | set_id | name | image|
+---+---------+--------+------+------+
| a | asdf    | fdsaf  |loler | blah |
+------------------------------------+
```

custom_properties

```
| id | card_id | game_id | name | type | vint | vstr |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+
| f  | a       | asdf    | range| 1    | 12   |      |
| b  | a       | asdf    | rank | 0    |      | face |
+----+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

the resulting table would look like this, **where the columns `range` and `rank` are derived from `custom_properties.name`**

```
|id | game_id | set_id | name | image | range | rank |
+---+---------+--------+------+-------+-------+------+
|a  | asdf    | fdsaf  | loler| blah  | 12    | face |
+---+---------+--------+------+-------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Retract my answer in light of the new info, my approach is not applicable.

Comment: Getting the idea that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  Cards.id,
        Cards.game_id,
        Cards.set_id,
        Cards.name,
        Cards.id,
        Cards.image,
        CASE 
            WHEN Custom_Properties.type = 1 THEN 
                 Custom_Properties.vint
            ELSE 
                 Custom_Properties.vstr 
        END as Range
        Custom_Properties.vstr as rank
FROM Cards INNER JOIN Custom_Properties
        ON Cards.id = Custom_Properties.card_ID
WHERE Cards.Name = 'loller'
```

Comment: For sqlite isn't it CASE ? ( I maybe be wrong... ) As in: ' CASE WHEN ( Custom_Properties.type = 1) THEN Custom_Properties.vint END as Range '

Comment: Getting the error `ERROR: SQL error near line 1: near "Custom_Properties": syntax
error`
Also, when I moved a couple things around it said `Unknown function IF`. 
The idea is that Rank and range aren't actual values that exist in my database, the idea is it's supposed to grab the value of the custom_properties.name and use that as a column name.

Comment: @kelton52 iUpdated my answer using `CASE` as Niall added

Comment: when removing `Custom_Properties.vstr as rank` it works. Also, again, the idea is I'm going to have more than two custom proporties, and I'll be needing them dynamically added to the list. This puts them all into one list under a Range column. The idea is one column per custom property.

Comment: Actually to add to my last statement, it gives me a row back for each custom property, instead of a new column for each extra property

Comment: I added something that should help you understand what I'm after.